# Locus of a vertex of a triangle inside an equilateral one, under an integer constraint

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, elliptic-curves, geometric-construction

Given an equilateral triangle $ABC$, we choose a point $D$ inside it, determining a new triangle $ADB$.
[image]
We draw the circles with centers in $A$ and in $B$ passing by $D$, determining the new points $F$ and $G$ on the side $AB$.

These two points define the segment $AF$ (blue), $FG$ (green), and $GB$ (red). We denote $\alpha=\overline{AF}$, $\gamma=\overline{FG}$, and $\beta=\overline{GB}$.

[image]

So far, I was able to prove that if  $\frac{\gamma^2}{2\alpha\beta}=1$, then $D$ lies on the arc of the circle with center in the midpoint $M$ of the side $AB$, and with diameter equal to $\overline{AB}$ (in these conditions, $ABD$ is a right triangle).
[image]

> **On which curves lies the point $D$ if** 
>   $$
> \frac{\gamma^2}{2\alpha\beta}=n,
> $$ 
>   **where $n\in\{2,3,4\ldots\}$?**

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will find a nice description of the curve without using coordinates.

Let $A = (-1, 0)$, $B = (1, 0)$ and $D = (x, y)$. Then it is easy to prove that
$$\alpha = 2 - \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2} \qquad \beta = 2 - \sqrt{(x + 1)^2 + y^2}$$
$$\gamma = \sqrt{(x + 1)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2} - 2$$
Therefore, the equation $\gamma^2 = 2 n \alpha \beta$ amounts to:
$$\left [\sqrt{(x + 1)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2} - 2 \right ]^2 = 2 n \left [2 - \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2} \right ] \left [ 2 - \sqrt{(x + 1)^2 + y^2} \right ]$$

Indeed, if $n = 1$ then the equation reduces to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, which represents the circle having diameter $AB$. If $n > 1$, the equation represents a curve having a branch shaped like an oval which becomes "pointy" as $n$ increases.

If we choose $D$ on the altitude of the triangle, it is easy to see that $\frac {\gamma^2} {2 \alpha \beta} \to \infty$ as $D$ approaches $C$. So the answer to the related question is yes.

Comment: Thanks Luca! Nice answer! Do you have any idea  how to draw such curves with Geogebra?

Comment: I exploit your cleverness a bit more:  Supposing to exclude the points $D$ lying on the altitude, does your answer include the case in which (also) $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are integers?

Comment: On GeoGebra you can create a slider  `n` and then simply write `(sqrt((x + 1)² + y²) + sqrt((x - 1)² + y²) - 2)² = 2n (2 - sqrt((x - 1)² + y²)) (2 - sqrt((x + 1)² + y²))` to create the corresponding implicit curve.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to ask for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ to be integers unless you specify the length of $AB$.

Comment: Well, we can suppose $\overline{AB}=\alpha+\beta+\gamma\in\mathbb{N}$, and then also $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. If we fix $u \in \mathbb N$ and assume $\overline{AB} = u$, for a given $n \in \mathbb N$ there may or may not exist $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb N$ such that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = u$, $\frac {\gamma^2} {2 \alpha \beta} = n$ *and* $D$ belongs to the triangle. This looks like a completely different (certainly more algebraic) problem from the one in the original post. May I ask you what's the motivation behind it?

Comment: I see. May be I will post another question. The motivation you asked is that I conjectured that, excluding the points on the altitude of ABC, there is not solution for the three conditions you mentioned ($\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are integers, $D$ is inside the equilateral triangle, $\frac{\gamma^2}{2\alpha\beta}=n$) with $n\geq 3$. Then, In order to devise a proof of such conjecture, I thought I needed to know on which locus lies $D$. But I was able to solve only the case with $n=1$.

Comment: By the way, Luca: I tried to apply your formula on Geogebra (by means of the ImplicitCurve command in the Input Bar), but it always says that my object is "undefined", likely because it is not polynomial. I am not an expert, can you please explain me how to correctly implement your solution?

Comment: You can simply copy and paste the equation in the Input Bar. If you want to use the ImplicitCurve command, you have to input a function, not an equation: just replace `=` with `-` and give the expression as the argument. (I'm using GeoGebra Classic 5, I don't know about other versions.)

Comment: Yes! Thanks, Luca! I have an old version, but I used Classic 5 and it works perfectly. Thanks also for all your comments/suggestions. Soon I will post a similar question (conjecture) involving the integers. Thanks again!